# ¿ Como puedo solucionar Fallo de iconos en Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows10, icons

Desde hace un tiempo tengo un problema a la hora de buscar aplicaciones mediante el buscador de Windows, pues no se llega a cargar la imagen del icono de varias aplicaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De qué modo podría solucionar esto?

Muchas gracias. ❤

Comment: ¿Qué le falta a la pregunta para estar bien formualda?

Comment: Oh, vale. Lo siento. ¿Sabes de algún lugar donde pueda preguntar esto?  Y procedo a cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: Lo puedes preguntar en [su], pero esa comunidad sólo es en inglés. Lamentablemente aquí no es el sitio adecuado para esa pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no funciona ejecutar

```
ie4uinit.exe -show
```

Trata Reseteando la base de datos de iconos de Windows, Lo puedes hacer abriendo un CMD y ejecutando los siguientes comandos uno por uno

```
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
CD /d %userprofile%/AppData/Local
DEL IconCache.db /a
```

Y ultima forma que te puedo proporcionar es abrir un CMD y escribir los siguientes comandos

```
cd C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
del iconcache*
```

Comment: Uhh, muchas gracias pana! Voy a probarlo. De todos mods es extraños pues solo sale así en el buscador. en la barra de tareas se muestran correctamente.

Comment: No repitas la respuesta, puedes editar la primera. Por favor leer [answer]. En todo caso, la pregunta seguramente termine cerrada, por estar fuera de la temática del sitio. Evita responder preguntas así, ya que tu respuesta se pierde. Saludos

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y persiste igual. Probaré a reiniciar, pero gracias igual :)

Answer (score 0):

Abre la ventana de "Ejecutar" con "Win" + "R" y escribe

```
ie4uinit.exe -show
```

El comando sirve para reconstruir el cache de los iconos de Windows 10.
Espero que te ayude

Comment: Acabo de ejecutarlo y parece que sigue igual. Tendría que reiniciar el sistema?